# How to know if HAProxy is down from java code?

Tags: java, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to route requests directly to a default server if HAProxy itself is down. Is there a way to know the status of HAProxy from Java code itself?

Update: Does monitor-uri do the same thing?

Comment: Well, you could try to call HAProxy and if it doesn't respond try the default (if you know it). There might even be a metrics/status API to call, did you check the documentation?

Comment: Couldn't find such API call. All I could find was server healthchecks

Comment: How are you doing it today?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.